# The tense in cunjunction with Konjunktiv

Tags: subjunctive, perfect-tense

In the sentence

> Wenn mein Leben zu Hause nicht so langweilig **gewesen wäre**, wäre ich nicht dort weggegangen.

why is it not

> Wenn mein Leben zu Hause nicht so langweilig **wäre**, ...

What can be the difference? "gewesen wäre" is Konjunktiv perfekt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminology is tricky here. You could call the form you are asking about *Konjunktiv II des Perfekts* or *Konjunktiv II der Vergangenheit*. In the following, I'll use the terms the *Institut für Deutsche Sprache* [has suggested](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/685).

Let's look at *synthetic* forms (i.e. those consisting of one verb on its own):

> Er **findet** es gut. (Indikativ Präsens)
>   Er **fand** es gut. (Indikativ Präteritum)
>   Er **fände** es gut. (Konjunktiv Präteritum)

The *Konjunktiv Präteritum*, despite its name, is used to refer to the present:

> Ich **fände** es gut, wenn wir bald wieder etwas unternehmen.

This is the reason why the form is often called *Konjunktiv II* – since that doesn't imply reference to the past.

Now let's look at *analytic* forms (i.e. where two verbs are combined):

> Er **hat** es gut **gefunden**. (Indikativ Präsensperfekt)
>   Er **hatte** es gut **gefunden**. (Indikativ Präteritumperfekt)
>   Er **hätte** es gut **gefunden**. (Konjunktiv Präteritumperfekt)

The *Konjunktiv Präteritumperfekt* is used to refer to the past:

> Ich **hätte** es gut **gefunden**, wenn wir letzten Monat etwas unternommen hätten.

Note that it does not have the meaning of past within the past (pluperfect).

Regarding your sentences, the first refers to the present and the second one to the past.

> Wenn mein Leben **momentan** nicht so langweilig wäre, ...  (wasn't so boring)
>   Wenn mein Leben **früher** nicht so langweilig gewesen wäre, ... (hadn't been so boring)

Answer (score 3):

Konjunktiv is not a tense. It is a mode. The sentence

> Wenn *(jetzt)* mein Leben zu Hause nicht so langweilig wäre, ...
>   If my life at home was not so boring *(now)*, ...

is in *Gegenwart*, this is the tense that matches closest to English *presence tense*. While

> Wenn *(vor 10 Jahren)* mein Leben zu Hause nicht so langweilig gewesen wäre, ...
>   If my life at home had not been so boring *(10 years ago)*, ...

is *Plusquamperfekt* (closely related to English *past perfect tense*)

But both sentences are in *Konjunktiv* (*subjunctive* in English).

The two other modes beside *Konjunktiv* are:

- Indikativ

  - Gegenwart

    > Weil *(jetzt)* mein Leben zu Hause nicht so langweilig ist, ...
    >   Because my life at home is not so boring *(now)*, ...
  - Plusquamperfekt

    > Weil *(vor 10 Jahren)* mein Leben zu Hause nicht so langweilig gewesen war, ...
    >   Because my life at home had not been so boring *(10 years ago)*, ...
- Imperativ

  - Gegenwart

    > Mein Leben zu Hause sei nicht so langweilig.
    >   My life at home shall not be so boring.

  (Imperative can only be used in *Gegenwart*)